# input certain textfield text and display it on the web page

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an web based "configuration" tool that will contain a lot of `Cisco` configuration templates for switches and routers.

But since I am new to `C#` I have some questions. Just so you know I am already familiar with basic strings etc... and I also have VS 2013 up and running.

This is not so relevant in this question, but just so I have mentioned it, I am using `ASP.NET MVC` (with `C#` as prog. language) and I am quite familiar with `ASP.NET MVC`.

Now here is the question, let`s say this is an`Cisco` switch template config:

```
interface eth102/1/1
description test-server
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan 100, 200
no shut
```

So what I am trying to do is to give the users an option to add following 
text fields:

```
ALLOWED VLAN: xxx
DESCRIPTION: xxx
```

Which means user types in VLAN ID and description for example, and then when he click on "submit" button or "get config" button name, then the user should get the complete template config listed somewhere on the page..
including the VLAN id and description that user typed in.

My question is, is it better to hard code template configurations or use an `SQL` DB?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb: hard coding is never a good stategy unless you are very certain, that the hard coded text is correct and will never change. If you have to change it you will have to recompile your app.

If you don't want to use a db that at least read your text from file. That way you can change or extend your text easily. Maybe consider implementing text tokens, that will be replaced by your app. That way you are more flexible because you won't have to rely on keywords in the text...

Comment: thank you for reply!

Well I agree with your suggestions, it's much easier to edit templates in the file then in the code because the code needs to be recompiled each time the change is made..

I can of course find some examples write and read from file, but in my case it's a bit more specific since I will change only parts of the template config and it's for example vlan id and description etc... Any examples ?